# SSL benchmarking For Openssl

Tags: tls, openssl, performance

I have client and server code for different SSL implementations like, openssl, wolf ssl, matrix ssl and I want to benchmark these implementation based on:

- Influence of symmetric key generation frequency.
- Influence of CPU performance.
- Influence of the asymmetric key size.
- Influence of the object size
- Influence of the cipher

How can I proceed? which tools will be helpful?
And also see this link
 [BENCHMARKING SSL PERFORMANCE](http://blog.haproxy.com/2011/09/16/benchmarking_ssl_performance/)  :

This kind of output is needed but i dont know what tool is used by them.

Comment: They write *"The client is inject + stunnel on client mode."*

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you take a look at the results and procedures listed [here](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/benchmark.openssl)

Copied verbatim:

- Install openssl-utils (with its depencies this will require about 790KiB of storage)

  ```
  opkg install openssl-util
  ```
- Then run:

  ```
  openssl speed md5 sha1 sha256 sha512 des des-ede3 aes-128-cbc aes-192-cbc aes-256-cbc rsa2048 dsa2048 | tee /tmp/sslspeed

  echo "|" `awk 'match($0,/r[0-9]+/) {print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' /etc/banner` `awk -v FS=": " -v ORS="" '/(Processor|BogoMIPS|Hardware|machine|cpu model|system type)/ { print "| " $2 " " } END { print "" }' /proc/cpuinfo` `awk -v ORS="" '$1 ~ /OpenSSL/ {print "| " $2 " |"} $1 ~ /(md5|sha)/ {print "  " $5 " |"} $1 ~ /(des|aes)/ {b = b "  " $6 " |"} $1 ~ /(rsa|dsa)/ {print b "  " $6 " | " $7 " ";b=""} END { print "|" }' /tmp/sslspeed | sed 's/\.\(..\)k/\10/g'`

  echo
  ```

Comment: Can you go on this link :  http://blog.haproxy.com/2011/09/16/benchmarking_ssl_performance/              I want exactly same output

Comment: @dhanu10896 Well, yes. Run this several times, graph it, and you'll get the same output ...

Comment: which tool is used in that blog post

Comment: In the one that you just linked, I have no clue. I'd guess openssl-utilities.

Comment: That will not be sufficient for this., thank for your response